# i need to load view using .xib when button pressed (without using view controller for this xib)

Tags: iphone, xcode

i am having a existing view controller which having buttons ,when one of this button gets pressed iwaant to load a view to load to display text

Comment: I don't really get your question

Answer (score 0):

You can look at UIView. You can create a new UIView instance by method : [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:]

[UIView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

Comment: wow, you managed to understand what he was talking about! There is one and a half lines there!

Comment: yeah, look at the question content and nobody can understand it but look at back the question title, I can get a little bit what he wanted to ask:))